# Class loses one name when you drop another class name from div using Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Sorry, this may be a long one so please bear with me. I have three sortable (jqueryUI) lists. List **all-colls-list**, **coll-selected-list** and **coll-grouped-list**. I can put items of list **all-colls-list** into **coll-selected-list** and **coll-grouped-list**.

So for example, I can put 'list item' into both **coll-selected-list** and **coll-grouped-list** at the same time, and the item will be retained in **all-colls-list**. When the item is added to **coll-selected-list**, a class name "selAdded" is attached to the list item in **all-colls-list**. When an item is added to **coll-grouped-list**, a class name 'groupAdded" is attached to the list item in **all-colls-list**.
 ex:

```
<li class"selAdded">Blah blha</li> OR
<li class"groupAdded">Blah blha</li> OR (when item is put in both lists)
<li class"selAdded groupAdded">Blah blha</li>
```

When I remove the item from either **coll-grouped-list** or **coll-selected-list**, it removes the respective class name for that item in **all-colls-list**. However, if two class names are present, and I remove only one, for some reason, it removes both!
So, if I were to remove "selAdded" from `<li class"selAdded groupAdded">Blah blha</li>`
it seems that it only leaves `<li>Blah blha</li>`

I've made a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/noscirre/xf8j2/

This is my code that removes the class name:

```
if ($("#all-colls-list li:contains(" + itemName + ")").hasClass("selAdded")) {
                $("#all-colls-list li:contains(" + itemName + ")").removeClass("selAdded"); }
```

and this is the code that checks for the existence of the class once it has been removed:

```
receive: function (event, ui) {
                alert($(this).attr('class'));
                if ($(this).hasClass("groupAdded") && $(this).hasClass("selAdded")) {
                    alert("both");
                    //Do nothing
                }
                if ($(this).hasClass("groupAdded") && !$(this).hasClass("selAdded")) {
                    alert("group"); //Do nothing
                } 
                if (!$(this).hasClass("groupAdded") && $(this).hasClass("selAdded")) {
                    alert("sel"); //Do nothing
                }
                if (!$(this).hasClass("groupAdded") && !$(this).hasClass("selAdded")) {
                    alert("none"); //Do nothing
                }
            }
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: why just not use .removeClass("selAdded");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the classes are being added and removed as you're wanting, but the code that's checking their existence isn't working properly. When you're checking for the classes, `$(this)` is referring to the parent `<ul>` rather than the `<li>` and so shows 'none', because the `<ul>` has neither the `selAdded` nor the `groupAdded` class.

I was using Chrome's inbuilt inspector to look for the classes while I was dragging things around in your fiddle. I used `console.log($(this));` so I could have a look in the error console to be sure what was `$(this)` was actually referring to at that point in the code.

Answer (score 0):

if you still need to check if it have a class...

```
$("#all-colls-list li:contains(" + itemName + ") selAdded").each(
function() {
$(this).removeClass('selAdded');
dp-_other();
}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use firebug or any inspecting tool, you can see that the classes are being removed correctly but the alert part of your code is incorrect

Try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xf8j2/2/

Although you should clean up this code and cache some jquery objects